# jflex: Why does this regex match?

Tags: regex, jflex

in my lexer I wrote the following regex:

```
"///"\s*[^@\s].*
```

I executed [byacc/j](http://byaccj.sourceforge.net/) in debug mode and it states that the following line matched the regex.
But why does this regex match this line?

```
/// @Service( version="1.0.0" )
```

I also tried `"///"\s*[^\@\s].*`, in case `@` is a special character, but it also matches. o.O

I thought my regex would match only a string that starts with `///` followed by optional whitespaces. Than any non-whitespace character except `@` must come, followed by any characters.

**Edit:** I'm sorry I meant the regex is used within jflex, **not** byacc/j.

**Workaround:** In the [jflex documentation](http://www.jflex.de/manual.html#SECTION00043000000000000000) I didn't find any `\s` escape sequence, so I tried this regex `"///"[ \t\f]*[^@ \t\f].*` and it worked. It seems that the `\s` escape character is not supported and silently ignored by jflex.

Comment: Any PCRE regex engine I am familiar with, would _not_ match the string `"/// @Service( version="1.0.0" )"` using the pattern: `///\s*[^@\s].*` (I removed the quotes since this is byacc/j specific).

Comment: But the regex used in byacc/j does.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that :). I just wanted to let you know that from a regex-perspective, you're right in your assumptions.

Comment: Are you able to view the matching process like you can in Perl?  That could help enormously!

Comment: JFlex seems to transform the given regex into a state machine. So in the generated Yylex.java file are no longer the specified regular expressions contained. Would this state machine anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is correct, before version 1.5.0 `\s` was not a special escape sequence in JFlex, and just meant the letter `s`. Starting with version 1.5.0, the regexp should work as expected.

`@` is not a special character and doesn't need escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Is the \ being escaped so that the regex being passed is actually `"///"s[^@s].*`

Try double escaping so you use `"///"\\s[^@\\s].*`